# Location.getSpeed(): how to update TextView to zero after stopping car

Tags: android

Very strange. When I stop my car, the TextView showing my velocity has a value greater than zero. That doesn't change until I drive again.

This is my code:

```
public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {

    double dSpeed = location.getSpeed() * 3.6;

    if(location.hasSpeed()) {
        tvKmh.setText(String.valueOf((int)dSpeed));
    } else {
        tvKmh.setText("0");
    }
}
```

There's no difference to that:

```
public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {

    double dSpeed = location.getSpeed() * 3.6;
    tvKmh.setText(String.valueOf((int)dSpeed));
}
```

How can I detect that there's no speed when location isn't changed?

LocationManager is defined like this:

```
locationManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 1000, 10, this);
```

Comment: I hope you're not driving around to do geolocation unit tests. You can use `ACCESS_MOCK_LOCATION` and the developer tools to test this more easily (and safely).

Comment: have you found ans for this

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you need a TimerTask that checks if the current location's speed is zero and updates accordingly.  Maybe run it once a second.

Comment: I had this idea too but I want to avoid timer tasks if it's possible.